# Recursive formula problem in Dynamic programming

Tags: recursion, programming

For my cs class Ive been given the following task.
I have n different beers, and the i'th beer has a price of p[i].
the prices are: p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKwrf.jpg) = 2, p[2] = 3, p[3] = 2, p[4] = 1, p[5] = 4.
I also have c coins, and I wish to figure out how many ways I can spend all the money on beers, with n = 5, and c = 5.

I know that there are 4 possible ways I can spend the money, (p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKwrf.jpg),p[2]), (p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKwrf.jpg),p[3],p[4]), (p[2],p[3]), (p[4],p[5]).

The task is to write a recursive formula, for the number of ways I can spend all my c money.

For now, I have this recursive formula:

N(C,i) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if C $<$ 0 or i $<$ 0 }\\
1 &\text{if C = 0}\\
N(C,i-1)+N(C-p_i,i) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

But I'm not sure if it's correct. I tried using https://recursion.vercel.app to generate a recursion tree from some code I wrote, which should imitate the recursion formula. The generator returns 11 though, but should return 4. Not sure if my code is correct.

I could really use some help, if someone can see if my recursion formula is wrong, or my code is wrong. [image]

Comment: Please define your notations. What is $N(C,i)$? Also, it seems to me that the problem may comes from the fact that your recursion may consider all the permutations of your 4 solutions. This makes 12 solutions in total.

Comment: The layout got a little messed up, but N(C,i) is just the recursive formula you are seeing, with c (number of coins) and i(the i'th beer)

Comment: @ninjarubberband: The dupe Matthew Towers linked to is one of your other questions.  Did you see that an answer has been posted to it?